# Write higher-order function that is passed an anonymous function as parameter

Tags: go, lambda, closures, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

Here's how to reproduce this code: https://play.golang.org/p/ostuT1QFV4C**

I'm attempting to write a function that will allow me to pass any method that is used to get data and convert it to a string. This is an attempt to get a better understanding of how to use higher-order functions in Go.

```
func getConfigsFunc(getData func() ([]byte, error)) string {
    b, err := getData()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    str := string(b) // convert content to a 'string'
    return str
}
```

I've tried to use this function in a few different ways, but none of them are working right.

For example, in one of the cases in which I might use this, I could construct an anonymous function that closes around a variable and returns a function that accepts no parameters and returns `([]byte, error)`. Theoretically, this approach would allow me to wrap any code that gets data as long as I can return an anonymous method that accepts no parameters and returns `([]byte, error)`.

However, my attempts to implement this have failed.

First, I tried this:

```
getNfsConfigsFunc := func() ([]byte, error) {
        return ioutil.ReadFile("nfsConfigs.json")
    }()
```

However, I get:

> assignment mismatch: 1 variable but func literal returns 2 values

(For reference, `ioutil.ReadFile(..)` returns `([]byte, error)`.)

I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that my error meant that the anonymous function was executing immediately (like an IIFE in Javascript), so I tried wrapping the inner portion in a function (to try to force the anonymous function to return a function, rather than 2 values), like this:

```
getNfsConfigsFunc := func() ([]byte, error) {
        return nil, func() ([]byte, error) {
            return ioutil.ReadFile("nfsConfigs.json")
        }
    }()
```

but the IDE forces me to add "nil, " to part of the anonymous function, which seems to violate what I was intending to do (unless I'm misunderstanding something). Regardless, it gives me this error:

> ./main.go:247:20: assignment mismatch: 1 variable but func literal
>   returns 2 values ./main.go:248:15: cannot use func literal (type
>   func() ([]byte, error)) as type error in return argument:
>           func() ([]byte, error) does not implement error (missing Error method)

Is it possible for me to do what I'm trying to do with Go?

For completeness, the contents of `nfsConfigs.json` look like this:

```
{
    "nfsURLBase" : "http://example.url.path.com/",
    "nfsFsBase" : "/data/nfs/path/to/files"
}
```

Comment: The first snippet attempts to assign the result of calling the anonymous function to `getNfsConfigsFunc`. The compiler reports an error because the function returns two values, but there's only one variable in the assignment.  Fix the code by removing the trailing `()`.  With the parens removed, the snippet assigns the anonymous function to the variable `getNfsConfigsFunc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing

```
getNfsConfigsFunc := func() ([]byte, error) {
        return ioutil.ReadFile("nfsConfigs.json")
}()
```

Does not create an anonymous function. It *calls* the anonymous function, because of the training`()`.

It should be just:

```
getNfsConfigsFunc := func() ([]byte, error) {
        return ioutil.ReadFile("nfsConfigs.json")
}
```